# a decent way to lint and style your vue.js code

Tags: vue.js, styles, lint, linter

is there a lint rule or something to get this structure of code when linting in vue.js?

```html
      <b-col sm="10">
        <b-form-input id="input-name" 
                      placeholder="Enter your name" 
                      v-model="inputName">
        </b-form-input>
      </b-col>
```

instead of this:

```html
      <b-col sm="10">
        <b-form-input id="input-name" placeholder="Enter your name" v-model="inputName">
        </b-form-input>
      </b-col>
```

Comment: You can limit the number of attributes per line by using the rule `max-attributes-per-line`: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/max-attributes-per-line.md

Comment: @Jns That seems like a good answer to me :)

Comment: found this: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/html-indent.md

Answer (score 0):

For linting and styling in Vue.js projects, consider the following best practices:

1. ESLint with Vue.js Plugin:

Use ESLint with the Vue.js plugin (eslint-plugin-vue) for specific Vue.js rules.

2. Prettier:

Use Prettier for automatic code formatting and style consistency.

Install Prettier:

3. EditorConfig:

Include an .editorconfig file for consistent coding styles across different editors/IDEs.

4. Vue CLI Presets:

When starting a project with Vue CLI, select ESLint and Prettier for a quick setup.
Husky and lint-staged:

```
npm install husky lint-staged --save-dev
```

Implement Husky and lint-staged for pre-commit hooks to run ESLint and Prettier on staged files.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?